# Matlab - Issue with evaluating anonymous function using arrayfun

Tags: matlab, anonymous-function

I'm encountering the following Matlab error:

```
??? Input argument "Va4" is undefined.

Error in ==>
sym.matlabFunction>makeFhandle/@(Va1,Va4,Vm1,Vm4)reshape([cos(conj(Va1)-conj(Va4)).*conj(Vm1).*conj(Vm4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1)+Vm1.*Vm4.*cos(Va1-Va4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1),sin(conj(Va1)-conj(Va4)).*conj(Vm1).*conj(Vm4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1)+Vm1.*Vm4.*sin(Va1-Va4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1),Vm4.*sin(Va1-Va4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1)+sin(conj(Va1)-conj(Va4)).*conj(Vm4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1),Vm1.*(6.25e2./3.6e1)+conj(Vm1).*(6.25e2./3.6e1)-Vm4.*cos(Va1-Va4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1)-cos(conj(Va1)-conj(Va4)).*conj(Vm4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1)],[2,2])
```

I'm trying to evaluate an anonymous function, a 2x2 matrix, at a point as follows

```
J = @(Va1,Va4,Vm1,Vm4) reshape( ...
    [cos(conj(Va1)-conj(Va4)).*conj(Vm1).*conj(Vm4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1)+Vm1.*Vm4.*cos(Va1-Va4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1),...
    sin(conj(Va1)-conj(Va4)).*conj(Vm1).*conj(Vm4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1)+Vm1.*Vm4.*sin(Va1-Va4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1),...
    Vm4.*sin(Va1-Va4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1)+sin(conj(Va1)-conj(Va4)).*conj(Vm4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1),...
    Vm1.*(6.25e2./3.6e1)+conj(Vm1).*(6.25e2./3.6e1)-Vm4.*cos(Va1-Va4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1)-cos(conj(Va1)-conj(Va4)).*conj(Vm4).*(6.25e2./7.2e1)],...
    [2,2]);

arrayfun(J, [0,0,1,1] ,  'UniformOutput', false)
```

Any idea what's going wrong?

---

EDIT: I should have mentioned that the function J is defined from some other function, so I am unable to provide the inputs as separate arguments. I have attempted to pass the input as a cell as: arrayfun(J, {0,0,1,1} ,  'UniformOutput', false); but I run into the following error

```js
??? Undefined function or method 'conj' for input arguments of type 'cell'.
```

---

EDIT #2: Solved by Nemesis below, we need to pass the cell input, A = {0,0,1,1} into arrayfun using A{:}.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the documentation of [arrayfun.](http://de.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/arrayfun.html)

```
[B1,...,Bm] = arrayfun(func,A1,...,An,Name,Value)
```

Each input parameter is a single argument. Since you pass your four input parameters as array

```
[0,0,1,1]
```

this is only treated as one argument. Just rewrite your call to the anonymous function to

```
arrayfun(J, 0, 0, 1, 1,  'UniformOutput', false)
```

resolves the issue. You can now make your code more parallel using e.g.

```
arrayfun(J, [0 1 1],[0 0 1],[1 0 1],[1 1 1] ,  'UniformOutput', false)

ans = 

    [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]    [2x2 double]
```

which will use the function `J` on all `[0,0,1,1]`, `[1,0,0,1]` and `[1,1,1,1]`.

Comment: Thanks. I should have mentioned that this process needs to be done somewhat dynamically, meaning, J is defined by some other function, so I can't manually split the input argument. As a result of this I tried using: arrayfun(J, {0,0,1,1} ,  'UniformOutput', false) but I ran into an error ??? Undefined function or method 'conj' for input arguments of type 'cell'.

Comment: In this case, assign your data to a cell like `A = {0,0,1,1}` and pass it to `arrayfun` by `arrayfun(J, A{:} ,  'UniformOutput', false)`.